# "Подумал-подумал" -- пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация

На практике в текстах (разной степени грамотности) встречаются два разных варианта

> Я подумал, подумал, и пришел к выводу

и

> Я подумал-подумал и пришел к выводу

Я не нашел, каким правилом определяется пунктуация в такой фразе. Интуитивно кажется, что обе формы допустимы, но есть чуть разные оттенки смысла, или, скорее, передаваемой текстом интонации. Верно ли это? Есть ли определенное правило, применимое в таком случае?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ответ на ваш вопрос можно найти у Розенталя: при постановке **запятой** подчеркивается **длительность** действия, а при постановке **дефиса** — **интенсивность или непрерывность.**

http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/44.htm

§90. Запятая при повторяющихся словах

1. Между одинаковыми словами, повторяющимися с интонацией перечисления для указания на длительность действия, для обозначения большого числа предметов или явлений, для подчеркивания степени качества и т.п., ставится запятая, например: Но он ехал, ехал, а Жадрина было не видать (Пушкин);

Различие в пунктуационном и орфографическом оформлении сочетаний с повторяющимися глаголами типа ***ехал, ехал,*** с одной стороны, и ***просил-просил*** или ***постоял-постоял*** – с другой, объясняется присущими этим сочетаниям значениями: в первом случае указывается на длительность действия (см. §90, п. 1), во втором на первый план выдвигается значение непрерывности или интенсивности действия либо его ограниченности во времени.

Comment: Лайк. Полезная информация. Слышал, что есть 2 варианта, а Розенталь объясняет разницу.